# Can I convert the mathjax data/text to simple text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mathjax

I'm trying to convert mathjax text

```
(\( \mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \} \))
```

to more readable format:

```
N={0,1,2,3,...}
```

in an ide(pycharm etc) .
Is there a way to do it in Python?

Comment: what is "simple text"? how should a derivative be displayed? Is LaTeX a possibility?

Comment: @cards They showed what they want in the question; I've made the formatting clearer.

Comment: There is a way but it will be too complicated to explain in one answer. You should probably use a tool like `pandoc`.